# Params issue with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm having trouble with what I feel should be a simple issue. I'm trying to create a basic match score reporting app and I'm trying to create a match and the match players simultaneously.

My models:

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :match_players

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :match_players
end

class MatchPlayer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :match
end
```

My form:

```
.container
  %h1 Log a completed match

  = simple_form_for @match do |f|
    = f.input :played_at, html5: true
    = f.simple_fields_for :match_player do |mp|
      = mp.input :player_id, collection: Player.all, label_method: lambda { |player| player.first_name + " " + player.last_name }
    = f.submit "Submit Match Score"
```

My controller action and params:

```
def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)

    if @match.save
      player = MatchPlayer.create(player: current_player, match: @match)
      opponent = MatchPlayer.create(player: Player.find(match_params[:match_player_attributes][:player_id], match: @match))
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:played_at, match_player_attributes: [:player_id])
  end
```

Right now I'm getting a `found unpermitted parameter: :match_player` issue. If I change `match_player_attributes` to `match_player` in my params then I get `unknown attribute 'match_player' for Match.` The error is occurring on the first line of the create action (`@match = Match.new(match_params)`)

Any help would be appreciated!

---

**Edit following suggestions:**

Controller:

```
def new
    @match = Match.new
    @match.match_players.build
  end

  def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)

    if @match.save!
      player = MatchPlayer.create(player: current_player, match: @match)
      opponent = Player.find(match_params[:match_players_attributes]["0"][:player_id])
      opponent_match_player = MatchPlayer.create(player: opponent, match: @match)

      redirect_to(root_path, notice: "Success!")
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

 private

  def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:played_at, match_players_attributes: [:player_id])
  end
```

Form:

```
= simple_form_for @match do |f|
    = f.input :played_at, html5: true
    = f.simple_fields_for :match_players do |mp|
      = mp.input :player_id, collection: Player.all, label_method: lambda { |player| player.first_name + " " + player.last_name }
    = f.submit "Submit Match Score"
```

Now it's creating 3 match_players, one for the current_player and 2 of the opponent. What's going on?

Comment: You're edit completely overhauls the question and should be a question by itself. However let me give you a quick rundown of what you're doing. I assume you you submit the form with a single player filled for this. When you run `@match = Match.new(match_params)` you are creating the match **with the submitted match player**. You follow this up with adding the current user as match player and then **add the submitted match player again**. The create should simply be `@match = Match.new(match_params)` followed by `@match.match_players << current_player` then save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem in the simple typo,

Try to change:

```rb
= f.simple_fields_for :match_player do |mp|
```

to

```rb
= f.simple_fields_for :match_players do |mp|
```

Also

```rb
def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:played_at, match_player_attributes: [:player_id])
  end
```

to

```rb
def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:played_at, match_players_attributes: [:player_id])
  end
```

Here is [wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models) with examples

**UPD:**
From wiki I shared with, you can find this point:

> accepts_nested_attributes_for - an ActiveRecord class method that goes
>   in your model code - it lets you create and update child objects
>   through the associated parent. An in depth explanation is available in
>   the ActiveRecord [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

It means that you don't need to create `opponent` manually

```
opponent = Player.find(match_params[:match_players_attributes]["0"][:player_id])
opponent_match_player = MatchPlayer.create(player: opponent, match: @match)
```

Because when you send your params with nested attributes:
`match_players_attributes: [:player_id]` inside of `match` creation process `match_player` will be created automatically

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for your response - that's helped a lot but has led to a weird issue - could you let me know if you have any ideas? I've updated my original post

Comment: @DavidM updated, please, next time, move it to another question, because SO has some rules about it, enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks bud I was thinking from my perspective that it was the same issue (ie. getting the form to submit properly) but can see that from someone else searching in future it would be seen as two separate ones. Will bear that in mind in future. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I can see in your `model`, you have:

```
has_many :match_players
```

hence, in your controller and in your form, you must use `match_players` (**plural not singular**)

Thus, in your `controller`, you will have:

```
def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:played_at, match_players_attributes: [:id, :player_id])
end
```

And, in your `form`:

```
...    
= f.simple_fields_for :match_players do |mp|
...
```

Notice the last s of match_player in form and in controller.

Comment: Hi Sohail - thanks for that. It seems to have fixed that problem but has led to another. Could you take a look at my updated post and let me know if you have any ideas?

Also I noticed in your suggestions for my match_params you included both :id and :player_id . Why was that?

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark the answer as accepted so others might get help from it too.
Your edit should have been a new question.
We need to add :id in strong_parameters too so that we could edit already existing match_players.

Comment: Regarding your edit, it looks like you there is an issue in the code where you are creating MatchPlayers after @match.save, could you comment out these 3 lines after if @match.save! and check again